# Limiting the scopes of an OAuth 2.0 flow

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

I want to set up a OAuth 2.0 flow in my code.

I want my code, to be limited to specific scopes (even if someone accidentally writes some extra code to request additional ones).

Let's assume I want my code to be able to only access photos in facebook.

Is the only place to restrict the scope during the request to the authorisation server, e.g.

```
https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID
  &redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&scope=email&state=1234zyx
```

Or is there a way to enforce this restriction **when issuing** `client_id` and `client_secret` so that the following request will eventually fail?

```
https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID
  &redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&scope=email,posts&state=1234zyx
```

My use case is for google APIs btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough details provided to know what you are trying to accomplish; But generally:

- The OAuth client may request any scope desired.
- The resource owner
  (Could be end user "consent screen" or Google if using APIs) may NOT delegate some or all requested scopes.
- The Authorization Server may ignore some or all
  requested scopes for many reasons.